# extract data from object array from json field in mysql 8

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, object

I would like through a sql query to extract data from a json field in mysql8

TABLE :

- **id** | int
- **game_at** | datetime
- **scores** | json

Registrations in mysql :

```
id : 1, 
game_at : 2022-11-04 15:53:00
scores : 
[
    {
        "tr": "4",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "alpha",
        "week": 44,
        "id": "67"
    },
    {
        "tr": "7",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "alpha",
        "week": 44,
        "id": "71"
    },
    {
        "tr": "7",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "beta",
        "week": 44,
        "id": "67"
    },
    {
        "tr": "8",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "beta",
        "week": 44,
        "id": "71"
    }
]

id : 2, 
game_at : 2022-11-05 16:53:00
scores :
[
    {
        "tr": "2",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "alpha",
        "week": 45,
        "id": "67"
    },
    {
        "tr": "6",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "alpha",
        "week": 45,
        "id": "71"
    },
    {
        "tr": "3",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "beta",
        "week": 45,
        "id": "67"
    },
    {
        "tr": "7",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "beta",
        "week": 45,
        "id": "71"
    }
]

id : 3, 
game_at : 2022-11-04 17:53:00
scores : 
[
    {
        "tr": "10",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "alpha",
        "week": 45,
        "id": "67"
    },
    {
        "tr": "6",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "alpha",
        "week": 45,
        "id": "71"
    },
    {
        "tr": "9",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "beta",
        "week": 45,
        "id": "67"
    },
    {
        "tr": "1",
        "tt": "10",
        "type": "beta",
        "week": 45,
        "id": "71"
    }
]
```

I tried this to start :

```
$sql ='SELECT scores->"$.type"
FROM adresse 
WHERE scores->"$.poliste" = "67"
';
```

but it returns null?

For example, I would like to retrieve all the values **​​where**:

- id: 67
- type: alpha

  {
  "tr": "4",
  "tt": "10",
  "type": "alpha",
  "week": 44,
  "id": "67"
  },
  {
  "tr": "2",
  "tt": "10",
  "type": "alpha",
  "week": 45,
  "id": "67"
  },
  {
  "tr": "10",
  "tt": "10",
  "type": "alpha",
  "week": 45,
  "id": "67"
  },

to create a table

I read that there is JSON_TABLE or substring_index but I don't understand how it works. An example would allow me to move forward Thank you in advance

Comment: If you have to look inside JSON data to complete a query, it's probably time to start thinking about updating the schema to support those operations and extract the data at INSERT/UPDATE time. It will tend to be multiple orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Does this mean that my request is not possible? Does this mean that I have to change my approach and modify my registration table

Comment: You don't have to change the approach, but you would be well served to do so.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have an example based on the above information to extract the data I want

Comment: I did some calculations. If I have 30 players each with 3 recordings per week for 40 weeks on 35 associations, would this represent 126,000 recordings (no json) against 8,400 with my approach (json) ? What do you think ?

Comment: or save an array in mysql8? is it possible

Comment: The more rows will still perform MUCH better.